# Is there a way in stackoverflow to see only Java questions?

Tags: support, questions

I am a java developer. So basically i am more interested in java questions asked that are yet to be answered. Please suggest a way to filter java related questions here.Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java Most of these are not answered. And the list even refreshes :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java

Comment: eeeeew, gross...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read [How do I find topics I'm interested in?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics).

The feature you are looking for is called a [Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Think of a `Tag` as being like a filter.

You can:

- browse by `Tag`,
- search by `Tag`,
- add favourite/ignored `Tag`s.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Tags.

[image]

and then click on unanswered:

[image]